# Viewing Generated Workflow in Designer

Tags: .net, xaml, workflow

I am building up a workflow using the ActivityBuilder and ActivityXamlServices class.  When I try to view the outputted XAML in Workflow Designer, I get the following error: ArgumentNullException (errors in SetFlowElementModelItem).  It seems as though the workflow designer is having trouble parsing the XAML.  If I hand edit the XAML (comparing it to a manually created workflow), I can get it to display.  There are some minor differeces such as:

The generated XAML uses the StartNode Attribute (i.e. StartNode="{x:Reference __ReferenceID5}") whereas the manually created workflow's XAML uses a StartNode element (i.e. ...)

Also, the generated XAML does not have any  elements.

I find it odd that a workflow created by .NET cannot be loaded by .NET.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was an issue with the FlowSwitch activity.  We were not adding an activity to its list of nodes.  Also, we were not setting the class name.